# Does subcutane infusion of 0.9% NaCl can also lead to hyperchloremic acidosis?

Tags: intravenous, saline

I've [read](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6560584/) that intravenous infusion of 0.9% NaCl can cause a significant drop in plasma SID leading to hyperchloremia and metabolic acidosis.
What I wasn't able to figure out is if this can also happen when NaCl is given subcutane and not intravenous.
I also [read](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5575294/):

> As subcutaneous tissue has few blood vessels, the injected drug is diffused very slowly at a sustained rate of absorption.

So I thought that hyperchloremia and metabolic acidosis might not happen when NaCl is given subcutane because of the slower rate of absorption. But I wasn't able to find a source for that, this is why I thought this question might fit in here and that somebody might have the time and knowledge to tell me if my assumption is correct or not.

Comment: @IanCampbell I'm not sure, I thought of an amount of one to two liters. Is there a threshold of X ml/kg body weight for subcutane saline infusion?

Comment: @IanCampbell I read that subcutaneous infusions with NaCl, for example, are performed in nursing homes and eldery care to hydrate elderly patients, because a subcutaneous infusion does not have to be performed by a doctor. And there they also wrote that one liter is not uncommon.

Comment: Interesting. This is not a practice I have come across in the US, but it does seem that there is some literature about it at relatively low rates (IE 40-60mL/hr). Good luck finding an answer.

Comment: @IanCampbell yes, I'm asking this question from Germany. I did not know this practice wasn't also common in the US. Thank you, I hope someone might know

Comment: SQ infusion of saline is a common practice with dogs and cats, but their skin isn't attached like ours is so it can accommodate quite a lot. I've put as much as a liter in a single leg of a medium sized (30-35 kg) dog, with two liters total. No electrolyte problems ever occurred. But I've never heard of that being done in a US nursing home. I've only seen fluids infused IV. Perhaps the difference is in the US an IV doesn't have to be started by a doctor (and rarely is). A nurse generally does that on the orders of a physician, who doesn't need to be physically present and can just call it in.